# Pre-fill fields in a form with data from a ForeignKey class

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a

```
class SurveyAnswer(models.Model):
    rel = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer
```

And now i want to pre-fill a form with this "answer"s:

```
survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, created_by=request.user, pk=question_id)
form_data = {"question": survey.question, "answer1":survey.surveyanswer_set.get(xxx)}
form = SurveyForm(form_data)
```

What do i have to do with xxx so that i get e.g the first answer related to the "Survey" (ForeignKey). With pk=1 i get the absolute number.

UPDATE:

I have done now

```
{% for i in survey.surveyanswer_set.all %}
    <p><label>Answer {{ forloop.counter }}:</label> <textarea id="id_answer{{ forloop.counter }}" rows="6" placeholder="Type an answer option" cols="45" name="answer{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ i.answer }}</textarea></p>
{% endfor %}
```

If somebody know how to do it nicer in views please give me a hint.

UPDATE 2:

This is a bit nicer in views (but i think there must be an easier solution):

```
answers_part1 = []
for i in survey.surveyanswer_set.all():
    answers_part1.extend([i.answer])
answers_part2 = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4"]
answers = dict(zip(answers_part2, answers_part1))
form_data = {"question": survey.question}
form_data.update(answers)
form = SurveyForm(form_data)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is two ways to do this depending on your needs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Or if your form is a ModelForm you can use the instance parameter:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/